# Tricks to optimize vector operations for a referentially transparent language that compiles to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, immutability

I'm creating a compiler from a language to JavaScript. That language has referentially transparent functions by definition. For JavaScript, this means a lot of overhead for numerical operations such as matrix/vector sum, because you have to create new arrays every operation. I'm trying to figure out a workaround, but it is proving trickier than I thought. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: This accounts for about a significant portion of the research in compiling purely functional language. Did you do some research, read some papers, check how other pure languages handle this?

Comment: @delnan actually, yes, I've read lots of papers on the subject and a great book about structures by the Clojure's author. I read a lot actually. But I'm asking because I couldn't figure a way to solve this in JavaScript, as I'm limited to what it can handle. While JS is kind of fast in some cases, it is not as straightforward to compile different semantics to it without causing a performance disaster - I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get some clues in either https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki or https://code.google.com/p/v8/

I know they've both done a lot of work in that area.

Comment: The former compiles the insanely impure LLVM IR into JavaScript and the latter compiles conventional JavaScript into machine code. Neither has anything to do with OP's problem.

Comment: Javascipt is a target language with emscripten. Machine code is a target with v8 (from javascript). By chaining them together, you can see the design choices that they made for numerical operations and matrices. So, if you created a simple matrix operation in c, compiled it to javascript and ran it in v8, you'd be able to measure the efficiency, in terms of operations, of the design choices. Then, altering the c program, you may be able to see how well (or poorly) they handled different cases. As the OP is stuck, sometimes even a simple idea may be able to nudge him toward a solution.

Comment: But both compile *impure* code. OP doesn't struggle with compiling code in general, but with optimizing away copies in purely functional code.

Answer (score 0):

What is a common way of dealing with referentially transparent functions?

My take on it is that you'll want to cache the output of functions, but how do you deal with scoping and garbage collection?

What if, instead of a actually implementing referentially transparent functions, you do a best-effort. Expressions within the same scope will benefit from the cache but otherwise it will have to recalculate. This resolves issues with garbage collection.

Alternatively you could set up some global caching scheme that doesn't even try to do garbage collection but just uses some generic limited-space caching scheme with pruning such as: last-recently-used, most-frequently-used or random-replacement. This relaxes the garbage collection constraint.